# Probabality that given given sequnce has a value

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, probability, probability-theory

Consider a valid string with bit-wise operands (that is "xor" ,"or","and") and also "X" where X is 
a integer from {0,1}. Let us consider their are n number of "X" then their are  2**n possibles of strings .we need to find number of strings that have value as "0" and value as "1".

Example :

Consider "X&X" out of 4 possible,only 3 have value 0 and only one has value 1.

Can anybody help me when their are more than one bit wise operand in string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but I assume that the interpretation of strings is done by associating left-to-right (that is `0^1&0` means `(0^1)&0`). I'll use `|`, `&` and `^` for or, and, xor.

Let `s` be an arbitrary string with n `X`s that evaluates to 0, and `t` be an arbitrary string with n `X`s that evaluates to 1.

Then, the strings with n+1 `X`s that evaluate to 1 look like one of: `t|0`, `s|1`, `t|1`, `t&1`, `s^1`, `t^0`. The ones that evaluate to 0 are `s|0`, `s&1`, `s&0`, `t&0`, `s^0`, `t^1`.

Fixing a sequence of operators, let S(n) be the number of strings with n `X`s that evaluate to 0 with the given operators, and T(n) be the number that evaluate to 1. Suppose the i'th operator that you're given is O(i). Then, just counting the combinations in the previous paragraph for each operator, you have recurrence relations:

- S(1)=T(1)=1
- S(n+1), T(n+1) = S(n), S(n)+2T(n) if O(i)=`|`
- S(n+1), T(n+1) = 2S(n)+T(n), T(n) if O(i)=`&`
- S(n+1), T(n+1) = S(n)+T(n), S(n)+T(n) if O(i)=`^`

These recurrence relations are easy to encode in an O(n) dynamic program.

Comment: I did not mention to go from left to right,for example consider (1&0^1|1&0)=1 and where as (1&0)^((1|1)&0) =0 ,both have same composition but are separated by brackets. .we need to consider even brackets as they make difference.